# Extract pattern photoshop in image or generate with css?

Tags: css, photoshop

Is there any way to save as png the pattern:

```
Blending Options > Pattern Overlay
```

or some way to grab the pattern layer and generate css ?

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: can you show us your pattern image?

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/e8bKmIR.jpg

Comment: Move mouse over the pattern and you'll see the size. On your canvas create a slice with the same size where the pattern starts. Then you just save the slice to a PNG file ("save for web" dialog)

Answer (score 4):

Go to `layer` > `New fill layer` > `pattern`.

Create your pattern.

Then, go to `file` > `save for web` then select `png` and export.

To convert it into a css, when you `save for web`, select `HTML and images` option under dropdown, this will create html and images for your psd file. Open this HTML in a WYSIWYG editor and define the CSS for the created pattern.

There is no hack for directly converting psd patterns to css.

Answer (score 4):

- Click the "Paint Bucket" tool.
- Select "Pattern" from the options.
- Rollover the pattern thumbnail in the options panel. It will tell you
  the pixel dimensions of the pattern.
- Make a new new file at the dimensions listed from the rollover. Apply
  the pattern.
- Save

Answer (score 0):

You can always take a screenshot of it and cut it out. Then save it as a png.

Comment: the only option I found was to save .PAT